# WPF ScollViewer cannot stretch horizontally

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I got a problem with scollviewer control in WPF and searched the website, but cannot get anything.

My problem is that I have a grip inside of a scollviewer and I want to automatically stretch the gip horizontally. The code I used to test this function is as follow

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100"></Rectangle>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I searched the problem and got the answer to use

```
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

However, it did not work in my case.

Can anyone give suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? I copy pasted your code into a new project and the rectangle is horizontally stretched. Also the grid you mention in the question is it a data grid or a grid that arranges the layout of the application?

Comment: Answer lies in parents of scrollviewer. Either provide more information or check it by youself - might be you should change row width from Auto to *

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem in the DockPanel. It is fixed.